# Unable to uninstall programs since the Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstall, windows-10-upgrade

I have upgraded my Win7 Pro to Win10 and almost everything is working fine (suprisingly 99% of the already-installed programs worked perfectly).

But now when I try to uninstall certain programs, I get a message saying there are some missing files and the program is just "stuck" there.

I've already tried to look for the missing files in the "windows.old" folder, which I saved on a separate drive, but there are not there either.

I've also tried some uninstall software that are supposed to be "stronger" than the native uninstall of Windows, but no luck there also.

Is there a way to "force" Windows (10) to uninstall a program or a way to bypass this lookout for missing files?

Answer (score 1):

Run either [Geekuninstaller](http://geekuninstaller.com) or [RevoUninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com) - both free and paid. I like Geek as it is stand-alone and works with 64-bit apps and both have an option to force uninstall applications that maybe missing a dll or ocx, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe run SFC /scannow use an elevated Command prompt ( CMD in search box, then run as administrator, good luck

One other thought, try reinstalling the offending software, this should replace the ‘ missing files’ & add the uninstall routine

Comment: This area is reserved for answers, not comments and clarifying questions.

Comment: Does this problem occur with ALL installed software or just certain programs ? Maybe try installing something simple, such as VLC media player then try uninstalling, I use Revo uninstaller, best App for this I have found & it’s FREE...